# snakemake: Run some tasks on cluster and some locally

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, snakemake, qsub

I'm using snakemake to orchestrate an analysis pipeline. Some tasks are very small (e.g. create some symlinks) while others take hours. Is there a way to use `--cluster` for some of them but execute others just locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`localrules`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#local-rules) does just this. When the example below is run with `--cluster`, `bar` jobs are run in cluster and `foo` jobs are run locally.

```
localrules: foo

rule foo:
    ...

rule bar:
    ...
```